# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target JDK 1.7 with goal site

Tags: java, maven, junit, verification

On upgrading our project to JDK 7 and JEE7 I'm hurt with Verification Error, but without any usable information in the log, even with the debug flag turned on. I'm using the latest maven version available, i.e. V3.2.5 with all plugins having the latest version of today! Eclipse Luna and jdk1.7.0_76 64 bit from Oracle on win7. The VM argument -XX:-UseSplitVerifier suggested in other answers doesn't change any thing! But what I can say for sure is: With the maven goals: package, install or deploy given no Verification Error happens and every Junit test comes out green. The Verification Error shows up with the goal „site“ given! Then not a single JUnit test passes! Useless to say that the problem never appeared with JDK 6 on the same project which started more than 3 years ago and which runs successfully in production at many sites! Who has an Idea what could go wrong on generating the reports for the site goal?

Comment: The `site` phase, with the reporting plugins you've used, tries to generate the `Surefire` report among the other reports you've configured and that's where it seems to fail. Whatever stacktrace you see must be added to the OP regardless of how helpful it is or not to you.

Comment: You're right asking for the stacktrace. I had a closer look at the outcome my self and saw the mere junit tests pass when generating the site as they pass when doing package only. The problem is comming from the emma-maven-plugin! On commenting out the use of the emma-plugin site generation works as expected! I'll try to find out what is wrong with emma!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, used following configurations and it worked okay.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier ${jacoco.agent.argLine}</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[java](/questions/tagged/java) [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) [jacoco](/questions/tagged/jacoco) [noverify](/questions/tagged/noverify)